# Does the electron spin interact with the gravitational field?

Tags: particle-physics

I know that we can't envision the spin of an electron envision as something spinning (unless the electron has a non-stringlike spherical structure), but the spin does interact with an electric field because of its charge. Can't we say that it interacts with the gravitational field due to its mass?

Comment: Not according to the General Relativity. However the spin interacts with gravity in an extension of GR known as Einstein-Cartan theory. The basic difference between the two is the fact that the later has a non zero torsion.

Comment: Anyone aware of any experiments on this ?

Comment: The spin interacts because of the charge *and* because it's angular-momentum-like (cf. Einstein-de Haas) and angular momentum of charged particles interacts with the magnetic field classically. An interesting and more precise question would be if the spin of massive particles contributes to the metric analogously to classical angular momentum in the Kerr metric.

Comment: Particles with non-zero spin are not necessarily massive. I don't know much about general relativity, but something tells me, that spin coupling to gravitational field should be independent of mass, at least, in leading order.

Comment: @StephenG-I had the same question in my mind!

Comment: I think the experiments on spin-gravity coupling are not so easy given that magnetic moments have a dipolar nature. Except in some special configurations they average out when there are many of them together.

Comment: But spinning electrons áre influenced by the gravitomagnetism of the earth (letting their spin rotate, like the angular moment vector of perfectly round gyroscope slowly rotated about an axis in the Gravity-B experiment), or aren't they?

Comment: This would fall under the domain of "spin-dependent 5th force", of which there have been searches; however, a positive result is not necessarily attributable to gravity.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple minded answer: The electron is an elementary particle in the table of the [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) which is a quantum mechanical theory. A gravitational interaction where the spin could play a role would need the quantization of gravity, which is a matter under research and not finalized.

In effective quantization of gravity, the corresponding quantum mechanical particle, waiting a niche in a future standard model , is the graviton, hypothsized to have spin 2 and be zero mass.

An electron graviton interaction then  has the following Feynman diagram:

[image]

If the upper line one the left is an electron and the lower line descriptive of a charged mass, the electron interacts with a virtual photon with the electric field. The above is only the contribution from one type of diagram, a an exchange . Depending on the lower line's particulate structure more diagrams can contribute and also higher order ones. For a gravitational mass for the lower line on the right, the graviton would be the exchange particle.

The effect of spin comes in the matrix elements that describe the  wavefunctions to be integrated , so as to get the crossection.

In a similar way that one says that, given the appropriate boundary conditions, the electron's spin interacts with the electric field, one cans say that :given the appropriate constants and a quantization of gravity, the electron's spin interacts with the gravitational field.

Spin is part of the total mathematical description in calculating the wavefunction of the system, and enters through the conservation of angular momentum in allowing or forbidding some diagrams.

The basic numbers that should be kept in mind are the coupling constants at the vertices, where for photon the vertex is depressed by 1/137, but [for a graviton](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html) by 6*10^-39, which makes any individual particle state interaction not accessible to experiment.